# How do I find the URI of applications from the Microsoft Store for UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to launch an application from the Microsoft Store using a URI. Game Bar Widget allows you to launch applications only with `widget.LaunchUriAsync(uri)`

I can get a list of installed packages using the `PackageManager`, but there is no URI in the `AppInfo` and `Package`.

How can I get the URI of an application installed from the Microsoft Store? Not taking into account the standard `ms-settings:` `ms-photos:` and others

I tried to use `GetFromAppUserModelId(AUMID).Package.GetAppInstallerInfo().Uri`, but it returns `null`
I can find the URI manually in the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId`, but UWP does not have access to the registry

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/link-to-your-app gives you the product page on the Store, if that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093069/uwp-reading-the-windows-protocol-value-in-the-package-appxmanifest-programmati).

```
var file = await AppInfo.GetFromAppUserModelId(AUMID).Package.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("AppxManifest.XML");
using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);

    var docXml = new XmlDocument();
    docXml.LoadXml(doc.ToString());

    var tags = docXml.GetElementsByTagName("uap:Protocol");
    if (tags.Count > 0)
    {
        var firstContent = tags[0];
        string result = firstContent.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").InnerText;
        Debug.WriteLine(result);

        Uri uri = new Uri(result + @"://");
        if (parent.widget != null) { await parent.widget.LaunchUriAsync(uri); } else { await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri); }
    }
}
```